# mutt config: reply with address that mail was sent to

Tags: email, gmail, mutt

Okay so here's the deal. I've got a school email adress (say `romeo@school.com`) that is held on an outlook server. 
Because I really dislike outlook, I have this mail forwarded to a gmail address (say `romeo@gmail.com`).

I've managed to set up mutt and gmail so that when I send a mail from the gmail account, it seems as if it is sent from the school account (the "from" and "reply-to" fields show `romeo@school.com` instead of `romeo@gmail.com`).

Now, I've started using the gmail account as a normal email address too (putting that in contact info) so poeple start mailing me at `romeo@gmail.com`, yet some poeple still email me at `romeo@school.com`.

Is there a way to set up mutt and gmail so that it automagically replies using the correct email address (eg the one the mail was sent too in the first place)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, you have to also set up your gmail, so it sends e-mail from both addresses.

Then you can add to lines in .muttrc:

```
alternates "romeo@school.com|romeo@gmail.com"
set reverse_name
```

Comment: FYI, I was using regexp like alternates `alternates ^mail@foo.bar$ ^other@myfoo.baz$ ` which didn't work, whereas this solution works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [folder-hook](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-3.html#folder-hook) directive if you store your mails in folder.

```
folder-hook .      "set from=romeo@gmail.com"
folder-hook school "set from=romeo@school.com"
```

Otherwise you can use [send-hook](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-3.html#send-hook)

```
send-hook '~t ^romeo@school\.com$' 'my_hdr From: romeo@school.com'
```

Look at the this [page](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-4.html#pattern_hook) for hooks.